# Pass string variable to XmlAttribute of XMLSerializer

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

Let's say I have the following code, and want to serialize into the XML below the code:

```
class Human
{
    [XmlElement("OwnedObjects")]
    public List<WorldObjects> ownedObjects;
}

class WorldObjects
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string type;
    [XmlAttribute(type)]
    public string name;

    public WorldObjects(string _type, string _name)
    {
        type = _type;
        name = _name;
    }
}

Human bob = new Human;
bob.ownedObjects = new List<WorldObjects>;
bob.ownedObjects.Add(new WorldObjects(drink, tea));

// Serialize
```

XML:

```
<Human>
    <OwnedObjects drink="tea" />
</Human>
```

The line `[XmlAttribute(type)]` will result in an error.

Is there anyway to change the attribute name by passing on a string variable?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I must apologise I overlooked such an easy solution. Thank you for your answers.
Also, thank you Ben and dbc for suggesting an improvement on the design.

Comment: Why do you not want to have the output as:

<Human>
    <OwnedObjects type="drink" name="tea" />
</Human>

This would make de-serialization a lot easier

Comment: You must put `type` into double-quotes like you did for the `XMLElement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`[XmlAnyAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyattributeattribute.aspx) for this purpose.  It *specifies that the member (a field that returns an array of [`XmlAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.aspx) objects) can contain any XML attributes.*  Note that a property can be used as well as a field to construct and return a single attribute with the required name and value:

```
public class WorldObjects
{
    [XmlAnyAttribute]
    public XmlAttribute [] Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            var attr = new XmlDocument().CreateAttribute(XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(type));
            attr.Value = name;
            return new[] { attr };
        }
        set
        {
            var attr = (value == null ? null : value.SingleOrDefault());
            if (attr == null)
                name = type = string.Empty;
            else
            {
                type = XmlConvert.DecodeName(attr.Name);
                name = attr.Value;
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string name;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string type;

    // XmlSerializer required parameterless constructor
    public WorldObjects() : this(string.Empty, string.Empty) { }

    public WorldObjects(string _type, string _name)
    {
        type = _type;
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

[`XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodelocalname.aspx) is required in cases where the `type` string is not a [valid XML name](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#NT-Name).  A valid XML name must, for instance, begin with a letter, not a number.

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7t1GX6).

However, using fixed attributes such as `type="drink" name="tea"` may make it easier to create an XML schema down the road if required, so you might rethink your design.  `[XmlAnyAttribute]` corresponds to the schema element [`xsd:anyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256443(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows for any number of attributes of any name to appear.  You would want to specify that there must be exactly one attribute of any name for your `<OwnedObjects>` element.